# how to have connectable web part on two pages?

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer

I have two connectable webparts but i want to have them on different pages is it possible?
If it is , how to i solve this??

```
public interface IData
{
    string Mydata { get; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you connecting the two webparts together? I presume you have an interface class? this interface class needs to be in a seperate project and built. Add the interface class to the gac (dll into the assembly folder). Then add the dll to the references in both the consumer and provider webparts.

**EDIT**

MSDN Cross-page Web Part Connections

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd585662(v=office.11).aspx

**END EDIT**

It is possible, check this out:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37142/Connecting-Custom-Web-Parts-in-SharePoint

msdn example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597538.aspx

question answered by me:

[Connectable WebPart Problems......................?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52922/connectable-webpart-problems)

and

[Connection between 2 web parts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43326/connection-between-2-web-parts)

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

When you connect web parts you provide some information to Another Web part!

If they are on two different pages, you can use **Query String** to transfer information between Web Parts!

Below is an example of query string:
`http://server-name/SitePages/DesiredPage.aspx?selectedId=1`

So from Source Web Part you can do `Response.Redirect(aboveUrl);`

Now you can access it via code using `Request.QueryString["selectedId"]` on the destination page web part!

Comment: i have created two webparts that are connectable webparts but when i put them on different pages , they cant be connected , can i solve it?

Comment: @MorskiMartin updated the answer!

Comment: i have already created an connectable webpart , is u are not an beginner u know what an page is , i have pages , two webparts that connectd , but when uploading them on different pages they wont connect why ?