# Saving changes made in a webpart

Tags: web-part, event-handlers

I currently have a webpart with a table which loads documents in itself. Every row has a checkbox control in the first cell. (Default: unchecked)

I am using a second webpart which has a button. If the button is clicked the webpart should load all document rows which are checked. I want the button webpart to show this results.

The first problem i encountered was that once everything was loaded and the

```
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

event was fired the second webpart lost the first webpart as a provider. I solved this issue by saving the provider in

```
Page.Session["provider"]
```

But this saves the old provider with the old table in which no row is selected. How do i make sure that the changes in the first webpart will be saved when a event from the second webpart is fired? And will be available in the second webpart for use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the provider you're talking about is set up using web part connections then a post back shouldn't break that link, but you may be breaking the golden rule regarding web part connections which is:

> The provider should be able to provide the data as early as possible
>   The consumer should use the data as late as possible

This is to avoid the race condition where the consumer tries to use the data before the provider has them.

So your second web part may not be able to use the data in the click event which is very early in the page life cycle. It can the instead set a flag which you can then use in a later event like 'OnPreRender`

Comment: These 2 webparts are indeed currently set up using web part connections. And on first load the second webpart can find the provider. Clicking the button in the second webpart somehow breaks the link. In the click event i check for the provider. If (Provider == null) comes out true in the click event.

Comment: What about in the OnPreRender event?

Comment: In OnPreRender is does find the provider. On first load aswell on the click event.

Comment: So if all you do in the click event is to set a flag that the button was clicked, then you can check that in a later event when the provided is provided and ready to provide the data

Comment: It did solve the issue of losing the provider. But i still have the issue where the changes (unchecking / checking the checkbox) in the first webpart are not saved. And this might still be as you said be caused because i breaak the golden rule.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with per!

You can check out my answer here on another post :) it has connectable webparts and saving to sessions state:

[how to have connectable web part on two pages?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53030/how-to-have-connectable-web-part-on-two-pages)

hope it helps!