# Dropdownlist,SelectedItem From SpList show in Labels

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have a webpart that contains a list were i have values and columns in it.

In another webpart I want to use a Dropdownlist where I can select an item in the list that i want.

I want it to take that column from the list and show all the values in labels that i have in my other webpart.

Would anyone know were to start?

Comment: You can start by rephrase the question so that we can actually understand what is being asked! Remember that if a question is really hard to understand, you will probably not receive any answers and people will start downvoting it (as they already have).

Answer (score 1):

I think what your refering to is connectable webparts?

if so check this link out at my answer!

"dont worry about the two pages thing ;)"

[how to have connectable web part on two pages?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53030/how-to-have-connectable-web-part-on-two-pages)

hope it helps :)

Comment: actually I belive that he simply want to populate the dropdown with the values from the list - but I am not sure because of the wording of the question. I belive that we need some more clarification from the user - I will try to warn ya if the question gets edited.

Comment: lol thats no probs, I just asumed thats what he wanted as he stated "labels that i have in my other webpart " which lead me to belive he wants to connect a webpart with another I presume.... I was a hard reading tho LOL

Comment: Well - I *would* edit that.. but I fear that I may change the intended meaning.

Comment: I agree with you :) +1